# Similar computation for ALG_DES_MAC8_ISO9797_M1 in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, smartcard, javacard

I'm sorry if this might out of topic but could someone help me to define what algo in Java that has similar computation with ALG_DES_MAC8_ISO9797_M1 from Java Card. The DES/CBC/NoPadding in encrypt mode doesn't give me the same result. Unfortunately, in current situation I can't change the algo from Applet side and I need to find the java algo that has similar computation for creating the test tool. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 of ISO/IEC 9797 specifies zero padding. The problem with M1 padding is that no padding is performed when the block is already a multiple of the block size.

This has two consequences: plaintext that ends with bits (or usually: bytes) set to zero will have those zeros removed (at least up to the block size of the cipher); this means that the padding is *non-deterministic* for messages that may end with bytes set to zero.

The other consequence is that no Java provider seems to support it. I had a long conversation with Dave from Bouncy Castle and we decided that support was not needed for BC either. Basically, you'll have to use `"NoPadding"` and then remove the bytes set to zero manually, from the end of the resulting plaintext.

Most padding modes *always* pad. Because of that it is very tricky to implement padding modes where padding may not take place. This is certainly the case for Bouncy, where rewriting the padding interface would be required.

---

In case you are mistaken: bit padding (9797 M2) is supported by Bouncy Castle: it's called ISO_7816d4 padding in there because it was also specified for smart cards.

---

You've indicated this padding for a MAC mode which seems weird. That would mean a non-deterministic padding is used for a MAC, while usually a deterministic padding (bit padding) is used.

I don't think this will be implemented either. You're trying a cipher, so I presume that the MAC part is a mistake.

Comment: Maarten what about using ALG_DES_MAC8_ISO9797_1_M1_ALG3 in java card when you ensure that data block are always multiple of block size ? I think it was added in 3.0.4 java card version